# How to solve matrix differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

I have two coupled differential equations:
$$\tag{1}
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{z}_{1}=-H_{11} z_{1}-H_{12} z_{2} \\
\dot{z}_{2}=-H_{21} z_{1}
\end{array}$$
And I want to find the correlation functions:
$$\tag{2}
\left\langle z_{1}(t) z_{1}(0)\right\rangle, \quad\left\langle z_{2}(t) z_{2}(0)\right\rangle, \quad\left\langle z_{1}(t) z_{2}(0)\right\rangle$$

I rewrote the equations as a matrix equation to get:
$$\begin{array}{l}
z(t)=\left[\begin{array}{l}
z_{1}(t) \\
z_{2}(t)
\end{array}\right], \quad H=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
H_{11} & H_{12} \\
H_{21} & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
\frac{d}{d t}\left\langle z_{i}(t) z_{j}(0)\right\rangle=-H_{i k}\left\langle z_{k}(t) z_{j}(0)\right\rangle
\end{array}$$
Where $\left\langle z_{i}(t) z_{j}(0)\right\rangle$ is the correlation between $z_i(t)$ and $z_j(0)$.
I am unfamiliar with matrix differential equations, and I am not sure how to solve for $\left\langle z_{i}(t) z_{j}(0)\right\rangle$?

Comment: What does the notation $\langle z_i(t) z_j(0)\rangle$ stand for? What's the context of this problem: where does it come from, why are you interested in it?

Comment: Sorry, $\left\langle z_{i}(t) z_{j}(0)\right\rangle$ is the correlation. I wanted to make it as simple to read as possible, but it is a problem for a damped harmonic oscillator. $z_1$ is the momentum and $z_2$ the placement.

Comment: What do you mean by the correlation? Are there some random variables here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general solution to $\dot{X} = - H X$ is $X(t) = \exp(-tH) X(0)$, where $\exp(-tH)$ is a [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).  If $H_{11}^2 + 4 H_{21} H_{12} \ne 0$, your $H$ has distinct eigenvalues
$$ \lambda_{\pm} = \frac{H_{11}}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{H_{11}^2 + 4 H_{21} H_{12}}}{2}$$
and $$\exp(-tH) = e^{-t \lambda_+} \frac{H - \lambda_- I}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-} + e^{-t \lambda_-} \frac{H - \lambda_+ I}{\lambda_- - \lambda_+}$$